# PySpark add column if date in range by quarter

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a df as follows:

```
name  date  

x     2020-07-20
y     2020-02-13
z     2020-01-21
```

I need a new column with the corresponding quarter as an integer, e.g.

```
name   date         quarter

x      2020-07-20   3
y      2020-02-13   1 
z      2020-01-21   1
```

I have defined my quarters as a list of strings so I thought I could use .withColumn + when col('date') in quarter range but get an error saying I cannot convert column to boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `quarter` function to extract it as an integer.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df1=spark.createDataFrame([("x","2020-07-20"),("y","2020-02-13"),("z","2020-01-21")], ["name", "date"])
df1.show()
+----+----------+
|name|      date|
+----+----------+
|   x|2020-07-20|
|   y|2020-02-13|
|   z|2020-01-21|
+----+----------+

df1.withColumn("quarter", quarter(col("date"))).show()

+----+----------+-------+
|name|      date|quarter|
+----+----------+-------+
|   x|2020-07-20|      3|
|   y|2020-02-13|      1|
|   z|2020-01-21|      1|
+----+----------+-------+
```